# How to change active border colour of grommet v2 FormField?

Tags: reactjs, colors, cp, form-fields, grommet

I'm trying to create app theme with grommet v2. I'm using Form and FormField from grommet components to crate froms. When FormField is active the bottom-border changes colour to default `accent-1` and I can't change this border colour.

I have theme.js file which I'm putting to theme property in  component. Everything connected to theme works well (buttons colours etc.) I was tried to change accent-1 colour but there's a lack in Documentation about this.

in theme.js

```
export const theme = {
   global: {
      colors: {
         brand: colors.primary,
         text: colors.white
      },
      focus: {
         border: {
            color: colors.primary
         },
         accent: {
            1: "#EEEEEE"
         },
         borderBottom: colors.primary
      }
   },
}
```

I expect to change this colour to grey but it's still default colour

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue. I was able to sort of solve it by adding a global color called `focus`. It doesn't look like you are able to customize the colors of the FormField component.

## This works:

```js
const theme = {
  global: {
    colors: {
      brand: '#0CA7D3',
      grey: '#DDDBE0',
      grey2: '#9A9A9A',
      focus: '#0CA7D3' // added focus color
    }
  },
  formField: {
    label: {
      size: 'small'
    }
  }
}
```

> Notice that this may change the focus color across other components since this is a global color.

## This does not work:

```js
const theme = {
  global: {
    colors: {
      brand: '#0CA7D3',
      grey: '#DDDBE0',
      grey2: '#9A9A9A'
    }
  },
  formField: {
    label: {
      size: 'small'
    },
    colors: {
      focus: '#0CA7D3' // tried adding a colors property with a focus property inside of it
    }
  }
}
```

## Source Code

Looking at the source code for the FormField component,
it looks like they define borderColor like this:

```js
let borderColor;
if (focus && !normalizedError) {
  borderColor = 'focus';
} else if (normalizedError) {
  borderColor = (border && border.error.color) || 'status-critical';
} else {
  borderColor = (border && border.color) || 'border';
}
```

Here is a link to the component code on Github:
[FormField.js](https://github.com/grommet/grommet/blob/master/src/js/components/FormField/FormField.js)

Notice in the normalizedError case how they use `border.error.color` which is the property from the theme object in Grommet.
In the focus case, they set borderColor to `focus`.

It seems the component does not support specifying a focus color on the FormField component from the theme object.

Answer (score 0):

I used `styled-components`' `extend` like so:

```
textInput: {
  extend: `
    background: ${ '#333333' }; // dark-1
    margin: 2px 0px;

    &:hover {
      background: ${ '#555555' }; // dark-2
    }

    &:focus {
      background: ${ '#555555' }; // dark-2
      color: ${ '#ffffff' };
    }

    &::placeholder {
      color: dark-5;
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: 200;
    }
  `,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of ideas on how to control the focus color from your theme:

1. Define your own color set on `global.colors` and pick a color form the set to be the focus color:

```
const customTheme = {
  global: {
    colors: {
      deepBlue: "#003366",
      focus: "deepBlue",
    }
  }
};
```

2. Change the focus color object directly on the theme:

```
const customTheme = {
  global: {
    colors: {
      focus: "#000000"
    }
  }
};
```

Use the following Markup with your customTheme and you should see the focus color changing accordingly:

```
    <Grommet theme={customTheme}>
      <Box pad="small" gap="medium" width="medium">
        <TextInput placeholder="hi" />
        <Anchor href="">Anchor</Anchor>
        <Button label="Button" onClick={() => {}} />
      </Box>
    </Grommet>
```

Note: grommet colors also accepts dark/light objects, [read more here](https://github.com/grommet/grommet/wiki/Color-Properties).

For a live story example on the grommet focus behavior [go here](https://storybook.grommet.io/?path=/story/theme--focus).